# Sony DSC-QX100 -> "getTouchAFPosition"

Tags: c#

I try to write an APP for the Sony DSC-QX100.
I downloaded the "Camera Remote API beta SDK" - and I have no Problems with those
API´s.

My Question is:
Can I use the "FocuseMode"?
To set the Focus via my own App?

I found the API "getFocusMode" or "setFocuseMode" when I use the "getAvailableApiList"-Method
but I cant use the Focus-Method´s..

Answer (score 1):

I would first double-check if the latest firmware is installed on the DSC-QX100 to access 'Focus Mode' and 'Half-press Shutter' API.

Best Regards,
Prem
Member of Developer World team at Sony.